# observe data and select context strategy, depending upon the data values

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern, strategy-pattern

Here follows a very basic Java version of [Mudlet](http://wiki.mudlet.org/w/Manual%3aScripting#How_to_highlight_my_current_target.3F), a [MUD client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client) using Apache `TelnetClient` (not ssh).

Largely as an exercise, `Context` has, so far, just the one strategy, the `TargetStrategy`, which returns a `Deque<GameActions>` **dependent** upon the `GameData` objects values.

The idea is to add more strategies, and, more importantly to select the strategy based upon game data.  For example, pass the String target in `data`...

And then I get a bit lost.  One thing I'm fairly sure on is that a `Context` without `GameData` is nonsensical.  For example, it's impossible to select a creature to target without the creature's name!

The current flow, set the strategy, then set the data, is backwards.  Does this require a `StrategySelector` type class which takes the game data as a parameter and returns a `Context`?

`Context` code:

```
package game;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import model.GameAction;
import model.GameData;

public class Context {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Context.class.getName());
    private Strategy strategy;
    private GameData gameData = null;

    private Context() {
    }

    public Context(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public Deque<GameAction> executeStrategy() {
        log.info(strategy.toString());
        return this.strategy.execute(gameData);
    }

    public void setGameData(GameData gameData) {
        this.gameData = gameData;
    }
}
```

when new data is observed, then do...what?   Controller code below:

```
package telnet;

import game.Context;
import game.TargetStrategy;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
import model.GameAction;
import model.GameData;
import model.TelnetEventProcessor;

public class TelnetConnection implements Observer {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TelnetConnection.class.getName());
    private TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();
    private InputOutput inputOutput = new InputOutput();
    private TelnetEventProcessor parser = new TelnetEventProcessor();
    private Context context;// = new LogicalContext();

    public TelnetConnection() {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    private void init() throws SocketException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(props.getProperty("host"));
        int port = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
        telnetClient.connect(host, port);
        inputOutput.readWriteParse(telnetClient.getInputStream(), telnetClient.getOutputStream());
        inputOutput.addObserver(this);
        parser.addObserver(this);
    }

    private void sendAction(GameAction action) throws IOException {
        log.fine(action.toString());
        byte[] actionBytes = action.getAction().getBytes();
        OutputStream outputStream = telnetClient.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(actionBytes);
        outputStream.write(13);
        outputStream.write(10);
        outputStream.flush();
    }

    private void sendActions(Deque<GameAction> gameActions) {
        while (!gameActions.isEmpty()) {
            GameAction action = gameActions.remove();
            try {
                sendAction(action);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        GameData data = null;
        String line = null;
        Deque<GameAction> gameActions;
        if (o instanceof InputOutput) {
            if (arg instanceof String) {
                line = arg.toString();
                parser.parse(line);
            } else if (arg instanceof GameData) {
                data = (GameData) arg;
                context = new Context(new TargetStrategy());
                context.setGameData(data);  //data changes frequently!
                //strategy depends on data
                //put all this in another class?
                gameActions = context.executeStrategy();
                sendActions(gameActions);
            } else {
                log.info("not a i/o arg");
            }
        } else if (o instanceof TelnetEventProcessor) {
            if (arg instanceof GameData) {
                log.info("game data arg");
                data = (GameData) arg;
                gameActions = context.executeStrategy();
                sendActions(gameActions);
            } else {
                log.info("not a telnetevent arg");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TelnetConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very happy with this:

```
package game;

import model.GameData;

public class RulesForStrategy {

    private Context context = null;
    private GameData gameData = null;

    private RulesForStrategy() {
    }

    public RulesForStrategy(GameData gameData) {
        this.gameData = gameData;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        context = new Context(new TargetStrategy());
        context.setGameData(gameData);
        return context;
    }
}
```

because it doesn't solve the fundamental problem, that a context without data shouldn't exist!

However, I guess it will work...?